# Can Excel increase Cell 1 until Cell 2 matches Cell 3

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out a way to get Excel to increase a cell, A1, that controls another cell, B1, until B1 equals a constant cell, C1.

For instance, the industry standard to do a task is 4000 hours and is a constant; cell C1 = 4000.
Cell A1 is the number of work weeks my team must work to finish this task. Cell A1 drives a lot of calculations but arrives at cell B1, which is the work Hours necessary to complete the task.  I must change the work weeks (A1) to change the work hours (B1) to match the standard.  Changing A1 changes B1 (on a wicked curve, which negates using a straight up formula).  I need B1 to equal C1 by letting Excel change A1.  A1 will then automatically tell me how many weeks the team should work.  I cannot find a formula and I don't know how to increment A1.

The examples below show me hand-jamming A1 which moves B1 closer to matching C1.  C1 then gives me the proper number of weeks based on my

```
A1=10.00 B1=1900 C1=4000
A1=15.00 B1=2850 C1=4000
A1=20.00 B1=3800 C1=4000
A1=21.06 B1=4000 C1=4000
```

Ideas?

Comment: If C1 is **constant**...why can't A1="=C1/190" ? Or pull in `190` from another cell if it changes...

Comment: @pnuts I get that but it just sounds to me that the OP has over complicated things.  Your solution completely works but obviously doesn't automatically update because you have to run goal seek each time.  I bet a simple redesign of the spreadsheet could remove the need for goal seek.  I will +1 you because your answer does "solve" the OP's problem

Comment: @pnuts Yeah I agree that goal seek has its uses, you may be correct  in this scenario.  I just wish the OP would explain the "on a wicked curve, which negates using a straight up formula" for what seems to be a simple situation...IMO

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the formula in B1 is `=A1*190`. DATA > Data Tools, What-If-Analysis, Goal Seek..., Set cell: `B1`, To value; `4000`, By changing cell: `A1`.

The formula in B1 may be very much more complex and refer to various other cells and ranges.